# SQLC Override Bool Type PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlc

I am using SQLC and my YAML config file contains the following type overrides for postgresql:

```
gen:
  go:
    emit_json_tags: true
    package: "hmdb"
    out: "hmdb"
    overrides:
    - db_type: "hstore"
      nullable: true
      go_type: "github.com/jackc/pgtype.Hstore"
    - db_type: "text"
      nullable: true
      go_type:
        import: "gopkg.in/guregu/null.v4"
        package: "null"
        type: "String"
    - db_type: "timestamptz"
      nullable: true
      go_type:
        import: "gopkg.in/guregu/null.v4"
        package: "null"
        type: "Time"
```

Everything here works, but if I add:

```
    - db_type: "bool"
      nullable: true
      go_type:
        import: "gopkg.in/guregu/null.v4"
        package: "null"
        type: "Bool"
```

I do not get the expected result. I have also tried `boolean` and `bit` to no avail, both with and without `nullable`.

I have an update query defined here:

```
-- name: SetUser :one
UPDATE users SET 
    username = coalesce(sqlc.narg(username), username),
    email = coalesce(sqlc.narg('email'), email),
    phone = coalesce(sqlc.narg('phone'), phone),
    password = coalesce(sqlc.narg('password'), password),
    mfatoken = coalesce(sqlc.narg('mfatoken'), mfatoken),
    active = coalesce(sqlc.narg('active'), active)
    WHERE id = $1 RETURNING *;
```

But the generated struct looks like:

```
type SetUserParams struct {
    ID       uuid.UUID    `json:"id"`
    Username null.String  `json:"username"`
    Email    null.String  `json:"email"`
    Phone    null.String  `json:"phone"`
    Password null.String  `json:"password"`
    MFAToken null.String  `json:"mfatoken"`
    Active   sql.NullBool `json:"active"`
}
```

I want to use `null.Bool` instead of `sql.NullBool`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `schema.yaml` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    ...
    active pg_catalog.bool
)
```

In `sqlc.yaml` the entry should look something like this:

```
   - db_type: "pg_catalog.bool"
     nullable: true
     go_type:
       import: "gopkg.in/guregu/null.v4"
       package: "null"
       type: "Bool"
```

Then after `sqlc generate` it would look like this:

```
type SetUserParams struct {
    ...
    Active   null.Bool   `json:"active"`
}
```

So it uses `null.Bool` instead of `sql.NullBool`.